# How can I override images on migration?

Tags: 7, migrations, media

I'm migrating images from URLs and I'm mapping the image field with this code:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image', 'titlePhotos')
     ->xpath('/photo/@URL');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image:source_dir')
     ->defaultValue(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/default/files/images');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image:file_class')
     ->defaultValue('MigrateFileUri');
```

I want to overwrite files if they already exit when running the migration for the first time and on update.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MigrateFileUri destination has a class property which indicates what to do when collisions are encountered.

```
  /**
   * How to handle destination filename collisions.
   *
   * @var int
   */
  protected $fileReplace = FILE_EXISTS_RENAME;
```

What you want to do is, extend MigrateFileUri override `$fileReplace` to be `FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE` and then use that as your destination.

example:

```
class MigrateFileUriReplace extends MigrateFileUri {
  protected $fileReplace = FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE;
}
```

Don't forget to update your migration code.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image:file_class')
     ->defaultValue('MigrateFileUriReplace');
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Also, I found [this post](https://drupal.org/node/1540106) that was very useful.